# How do I install Symfony in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, symfony, cygwin, composer-php

Symfony provides a [wrapper/install](http://symfony.com/download), or you can use [Composer](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/installation.html#creating-symfony-applications-without-the-installer). Is there a way to get the installer to run in Cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I found to complete this was to install a Cygwin package manager, either [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg) or [Sage](https://github.com/svnpenn/sage) (I'm using Sage since apt-cyg is no longer being actively worked on).

```
$ lynx -source rawgit.com/svnpenn/sage/master/sage > sage
$ install sage /bin
```

---

Next we will install the packages required for both the Composer route and the Installer route.

```
$ sage update
$ sage install wget curl sed
$ sage install php php-json php-phar php-mbstring php-iconv php-zlib php-ctype php-tokenizer php-simplexml
```

**We should now have enough for Composer.**

```
$ mkdir -p ~/tmp
$ cd ~/tmp
$ wget https://getcomposer.org/installer
```

We can double check by asking the Installer.

```
$ php installer --check
```

If all is good, proceed

```
$ php installer
$ rm installer
$ chmod a+x composer.phar
```

Install Composer globally (put it in PATH)

```
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

If you want to use the alternate Symfony install via Composer, you should now be able to do that.

---

If we want to use the **Symfony Installer**, we'll need to grab it.

```
$ curl -L https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

If you don't have a timezone set in your `php.ini`, you should set it before trying to run the Symfony Installer or else it will complain.

```
$ sed -i -e 's/;date.timezone/date.timezone = "America\/Toronto"/g' /etc/php5/php.ini
```

An explanation for the sed command is available in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159369/164283). Set your own timezone as appropriate based on your location.

You should now be able to run the Symfony Installer to create your project

```
$ symfony new my_project_name lts
```

Where the `lts` part is for your version. Currently `lts` is 2.8.4. If you leave that part off you'll get the most current stable.

I hope this helps you (and perhaps me, next time I have to do this) save a bit of time.